# What does philosophy exactly do?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, history-of-philosophy

I need your help understanding philosophy. For some reason, I'm not understanding the objective of this subject. Frankly, I only had 1 semester of philosophy so maybe it isn't enough to really understand... But that's what I learned what it was all about(from what I remember.) : Philosphy is concerned primarely with the use of reason to arrive at some kind of truth.(Using arguments that are valid,etc.) Yes, I know this definition might not satisfy some experts on this subject, so you're here to help me understand exactly what it is.Now, what I also want to understand is what exact truths did philosophy achieve in any particular subject ? Are all the famous philosphers people who discovered what love is, what makes a good life,etc.? Because what I'm expecting(Which might not be correct) is the TRUTH about something and not diverse truths from different persons and you're here only to choose what corresponds the most to your personality. So, if someone gives good arguments and says life is good only if you're rich and another person says with support of good arguments that life is good only if you're modest,(Who is right?) then this is what I'm critical of! Because I'm expecting philosophy to be kind've like mathematics or the sciences. Finally, would you say that philosophy is more concerned with the human sciences than the natural ones ? Can philosphy say anything more on the origins of life, universe,etc? than science can't?

Now, I know I might be wrong with all my sayings and that I'm not having a correct vision of the subject that is philosophy, so that's why I'm asking your help to lighten my path!

thank you !

*I may add things later on..

Comment: There are six question marks here -- is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to narrow in on one specific concern? Keep in mind you can always ask more questions

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy is **one of** many human endeavours to find a meaning in life, and universe, and so on.

Of course there are others : literature, religion, magic ...

Some efforts regarding the understanding of phisycal world (the universe) evolved into scince (the physical ones).

Some efforts regarding the understanding of (parts of) human mind evolved into logic or psychology.

But there are also history, ethics, etc.

They also are involved with "basic" question : life, culture, society, law. Are they (hard) sciences ? I think not.

Are they deprived of interest and of contribution to increasing human understanding and awareness ? I think not.

Answer (score -3):

personally, i think u just identified one of philosophies greatest weakness, the lack of practical value.

philosophy improves logical thought and systematic thinking

but i think every time a philosopher philosophies they need to  ask themselves the question what is the practical step people can do using this new thought process.

A call for practical philosophy